# Keyboard missing right click on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, right-click

If you look at a Windows keyboard, there is a key to the right of Windows Key and to the left of Control key. It simulates a mouse right click on Windows. I recently purchased a wireless keyboard which does not have this key. There is only a function key between right side alt and control, and there is no other key. Is there a way to setup a keyboard shortcut that will simulate the right click instead? THis way I could do right click at cursor using my keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to send the same command with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) can also be configured to do the same thing.

Comment: @PseudoSu Thanks.  This info is not at all easily available in a google search.